# TS-7500 doesn't detect ttyACM ports

Tags: debian, arduino, tty

I have a TS-7500 board which runs 2.6.36 kernel and a Arudino Uno. When I connect the arduino to TS-7500, it doesn't show up a ACM device.

After running `$ modprobe cdc_acm`, dmesg shows the  following output

```
usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
cdc_acm: v0.26:USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

But why TS-7500 doesn't assign any port no (for eg. **ttyACM0**) to Uno in /dev. Ideally it should show a msg like

```
cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

Someone please clarify the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Arduino Uno connected to TS-7500, but I spent lot of time with tuning different USB modems.

Try to modprobe **ehci-hcd** or **ohci-hcd** and **uhci-hcd**. You have to make sure, that support for those USB features is compiled in kernel.

**EDIT:**
I checked your **lsmod** output. You are missing **cdc_acm** support. That is why you can't see ttyACM devices.

Your lsmod output should look like this (or at least part of it):

```
Module                  Size  Used by
cdc_acm                 8452  0
uhci_hcd               15568  0
ohci_hcd               14372  0
sd_mod                 15504  0
scsi_mod               55372  1 sd_mod
ehci_hcd               22028  0
usbcore                74268  4 cdc_acm,uhci_hcd,ohci_hcd,ehci_hcd
```

Look into directory `/lib/modules/uname -r/kernel/drivers/usb/class` you should have there cdc_acm.ko file.
If yes, than load it by modprobe cdc_acm.

If you do not have it, than you need to compile kernel and modules, with CDC ACM support.

Comment: Nothing happens when I run the command. Anything else I could try ?

Comment: What means "nothing happens"? Will it returns any error? Try lsmod command and post results. Also look into the /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/usb/ if there are mentioned modules.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I meant that nothing new happens. Please have a look at [**this link**](http://pastebin.com/vh9WRWuC) to see the outputs of commands lsmod, dmesg, and list of the modules u have mentioned. Everything looks ok. But still ACM ports are not allotted.

Comment: Pleas check EDIT of my previous answer.

Comment: And by the way. If command modprobe <module> is not returning anything, than it's properly loaded. You need to be worried only if there is any output, which means error.